# Как определить способ образования слов?

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Помогите расчленить слова на морфемы и определить способ образования слов:

- пятьдесят
- луноход
- пятиклассник
- быстрорастворимый
- перекатиполе

Answer (score 1):

Быстрорастворимый - слияние, луноход - сложение с суффиксацией (нулевой суффикс), то же самое с пятиклассником. Про пятьдесят затрудняюсь уверенно сказать.

Answer (score 0):

Сложение основ, "перекати - поле".